# ActionBar на 22 API

Tags: android

Использую `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">` но при этом, когда использую функцию "Preview all screen sizes" и выбираю в верхнем меню Android Studio 22Api (а также на 15Api), этот ActionBar все равно показывается. 
На других версиях Api (16, 17, 18...) его нет. 
Что можно предпринять, чтобы ActionBar скрылся?

Comment: попробуй использовать appcompatactivity

Answer (score 2):

в вашей *Activity*  в методе onCreate() добавьте следующую строчку:

```
  getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: Не могу добавить, как так "cannot resolve method  getSupportActionBar". В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: это зависит какие вы библиотеки используете и какие не используете (AppCompat, ActionBarSherlock и т.д.), а значит от какой *Activity* наследуется ваша *Activity*. Хотя если у вас нет метода getSupportActionBar() значит должен быть getActionBar(). Они взаимоисключающие

Answer (score 1):

У меня была такая же проблема, то показывался то нет, помогло обновление Android Studio до последней версии. Сразу все как надо заработало!

Answer (score 1):

Вполне может быть что это просто Preview AndroidStudio лагает.

На реальных устройствах такого может и не наблюдаться.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?